# What is the proper workflow for storing data without multiple instances of database models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, crud

I'm relatively new to web development. I am using ruby on rails.

If I had a website with blog posts, I would have a `Post` model inside my DB and would CRUD instances of it. What if I had an "about" page (where users can read about the blog) and wanted to edit a block of text on the "about" page? How would I go about updating the text displayed on that page?

It doesn't sound like it would make sense to store the data in a DB model as I would only have one instance of such model (since there is only a single "about" page).

What would be the appropriate workflow for storing and editing this data if I will only have one instance of it?

Comment: Your About page can be a simple HTML page you edit. Or you could make it a special Post.

Answer (score 1):

Static pages do not have any dynamic data - thus can be just plain HTML files or `.html.erb` in basic rails views.

All you need to do is create something like:

1. Have a route to `yourpage.com/about.html` inside your `routes.rb` file

```rb
get "/about", to: "static_pages#readme"
```

2. Have a controller to serve this route

```rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def about; end
end
```

Notice there's no dynamic data on the about page so we do not have to set any variables inside a controller. (like you would set `@posts` in your `PostsController`)

3. Have a view template with the data you need to be displayed on `/about` page

```rb
app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb
```

PS. If you'd like to bypass rails all the way you can drop `about.html` inside `public/` folder and check `yourpage.com/about` or `localhost:3000/about.html` in dev environment. (Look for `404.html` page for reference), but I'd keep with the rails way.

Comment: I appreciate the post. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, but I want to actually edit the contents of this page through the website the same way I could CRUD data through the website (i.e., I would like to have an "edit" button on the webpage that could let me edit the text on the page and update it). In other words, I am not looking to constantly edit and reupload a static html file to a live website.

Comment: Then it makes sense to be inside database, I'd go with normal model with just a single entry.

Although there might be better ideas to edit a page in-place (I'm never used any) - though you'll lose the changes each time you redeploy the page by not having a persistent data storage.